SQL Server AlwaysOn: a deadlock occurred on the secondary replica
I'm using SQL Server 2019, and have configured AlwaysOn. Someone executed a query on the secondary replica, at the same time, the primary replica stopped synchronizing data to the secondary replica.
How to make sure my sync is not affected in any way? (I cannot guarantee that the secondary replica will not experience a deadlock)
I use Zabbix to monitor deadlocks on the secondary replica, and once a deadlock occurs, I execute the kill
